# how to convert boolean expression to cnf file?

Tags: java, boolean-expression, conjunctive-normal-form, sat-solvers

i need to use sat solver for checking satisfiability of boolean expressions..

I have complex boolean expression like this

[image]

is there any automatic cnf file converter so that i can give it straight to sat solver?

I read the cnf format file.. but how to express this expression in .cnf file? i get confused when there is a conjunction inside the paranthesis and how to express --> and <-> ? please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions.

[Limboole](http://fmv.jku.at/limboole/) is an open source tool which I believe includes a separate 'propositional logic to CNF' converter.

More generally, you could also use a tool that supports propositional logic natively; some examples include [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/), [CVC3](http://cs.nyu.edu/acsys/cvc3/), and [Yices](http://yices.csl.sri.com/).

Comment: The SMT solvers you named are really overkill for SAT solving....

Comment: @DenisBueno: I kind of agree (SMT solvers do a lot more than SAT solving). In this case I don't really see a cost though -- modern DPLL(T)-based SMT solvers have SAT performance on par with the best SAT-only solvers, and they are not that much harder to use.

If you're willing to use the SMT-lib syntax, you can write pretty high-level propositional stuff and still use the solvers interchangeably.

I'll add that Z3, cvc3, and yices are being actively maintained and have fairly active mailing lists to support users.

Answer (score 2):

[SBSAT](http://www.cs.uc.edu/~weaversa/SBSAT.html) is a state based SAT solver that is able to accept a variety of input formats. You could take a simple expression and give it to SBSAT to convert to CNF. The [manual](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/sbsat_user_manual.pdf), section 4.10, describes how to do this.

Comment: I could not find such a feature in `SBSAT`. It is possible to specify the "trace format" as input format. However, this does not allow nested boolean expressions but only netlists of gate statements.